# Memory issue with NSArray and ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I try to write a program in Objective C that calculates some stuff. Unfortunately there is a lot to calculate and the Program is running a loop with 10000 iterations. The total running time is around 5 minutes. 
This isn't an issue but while it is running the memory the program uses goes up dramatically (above to 2GB) and I figure it is because of some Values that are not released. I narrowed the problem down to a creation of a NSArray inside a loop. The problematic code (changed it to concentrate on the problem) is this:

```
for (NSInteger k = 0; k<100000; k++) {

    NSMutableArray *mutableTestArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<200; i++){

        NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSInteger j=0; j<200; j++) {

            //simplified version, normally the valus for sub array are dependent on some other factors
            [subArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil]];

        }
        [mutableTestArray addObject:subArray];

    }


    //do stuff with mutableTestArray
    //change parameters that go into sub array

}
```

If I replace:

```
[subArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil]];
```

with:

```
[subArray addObject:@"test"];
```

it works fine. So I guess I somehow have to release the Array I created. But how?
I have ARC enabled and as far as I know if it is enabled I can't release objects manually. It would be great if someone could help me with how to change the code or hint me somewhere where I can learn how to do memory management correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use C arrays for this? 5 minutes for 10000 iterations is extremely slow.

Comment: in every iteration I have to change some matrices (100x500) and arrays (2000 elements). Thats what takes most of the time. Maybe you are right that it might be faster with C arrays but I actually don't care so much if it takes 1 min or 5 minutes. How much faster do you think it would get if I use C arrays instead of NSArray?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just throw in some autoreleasepools :

```
@autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSInteger j=0; j<200; j++) {
@autoreleasepool {

            //simplified version, normally the valus for sub array are dependent on some other factors
            [subArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil]];
}
        }
        [mutableTestArray addObject:subArray];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil];` returns with an autoreleased object and it will be released somewhere in the future, but not immediatelly.
Use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil];` and the array will be released almost immediatelly, because of ARC.
If you wouldn't use ARC the code could be the following:

```
NSArray* tempArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", @"test", nil];
// use the temporary variable
[subArray addObject:tempArr];
[tempArr release];
```

Because you are using ARC, you should remove the release.